# Active record sum giving the wrong answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm working on a project and I have to get the sum of an attribute of a active record collection. So I used:

```
@total = @records.sum(:cost)
```

However this gives the wrong value, for example if I have:

```
@records.each{ |x| puts x.cost}
```

I get 118.80 and 108.00

but for @total I get 680.40, which obviously isn't the answer, however if I use:

```
@total = 0
@records.each{ |x| @total = @total + x.cost}
```

I get the right answer of 226.80

If anyone can help me understand what is going on here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 680.40 = 226.80 * 3 if that helps in any way. But the issue isn't with the code you have shown us.

Comment: @records.pluck(:cost).sum

Comment: How is `@records` defined?

Comment: What SQL statement gets executed in the different cases?

Comment: Also have you overridden the getter method on the Record cost attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, as a record collection is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, not an `Array`. It means that if you call:

```
@object.collection.sum(:cost)
```

actually what gets called is this method: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum

And it will call `sum` in the SQL database, so the result gets influenced by the parameters of the query, e.g. groups, joins, etc.

While if you want to use Array sum, as in here: http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/sum

You would have to make your object Array first, via `to_a`:

```
@object.collection.to_a.sum(&:cost)
```

Comment: But in general the two ought to yield the same result, as the underlying parameters associated with the collection proxy's query is present in both cases, no?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Hard to say. I have an example where this is not true, although it is not exactly what I wrote above:

If you have:
`@records = Record.all; @record.last.cost += 1`
then `@records.sum(:cost) < @records.map(&:cost).sum`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

pluck the values of attr `cost` into an array and aggregate their sum

```
@total = @records.pluck(:cost).sum
```

Comment: This gives the right answer, why did my original code not work?

Comment: why using `pluck` + `sum` when `sum` does the same but faster? I edited your answer, you reverted the edit..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko apparently.. `@records.sum(:cost)` gives me the sum of all the records in that table not just the objects in `@records` (i faced similar issue earlier with ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.7) .. OP has tried `@records.sum(:cost)` with wrong answer